# Ruby: Yielding from a method that takes arguments?

Tags: ruby, block, tree-traversal

I've written a very simple, recursive, tree-traversal method in ruby. I want to yield the results of this traversal so that I can easily iterate through the nodes of the tree.

```
def bottom_up_traversal (node)
    if(node.has_leaf_children?)
        node.children.each{|i| yield i} 
    else
        node.children.each{|i| bottom_up_traversal(i)}
        yield node
    end

end
```

And when I attempt to call it, like:

```
 bottom_up_traversal(@root){|this_node| puts this_node }
```

I get a 'Wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)'. I know this is probably just something silly i'm doing with syntax, but I cannot find any (even basic) examples of this being done....which leads me to believe that I'm misunderstanding how I should be using code-bocks (something which is admittedly new to me)

So, could you perhaps tell me how I'm supposed to call this method, or where I've gone wrong?

Comment: it would help if you provided some data we could call the method on that would allow people to reproduce the error themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it wasn't the original method call, but the way the method recursively calls itself that was the issue, which stemmed not from me not really understanding how code-blocks work it seems.

Phillip's answer with extra 'yield self' calls worked perfectly.

Thank you very much!

```
def bottom_up_traversal (node, &block)
    if(node.has_leaf_children?)
        node.children.each{|i| yield i} 
        yield node
    else    
        node.children.each{|i| bottom_up_traversal(i, &block)}
        yield node
    end
end
```

called like

```
bottom_up_traversal(@root){|this_node| puts this_node }
```

traverses them in perfect order.

Answer (score 3):

In your method when you call `bottom_up_traversal(i)` you aren't passing the original block when you invoke it the first time.  Untested, but I think you want something more like this:

```
def bottom_up_traversal (node, &block)
    if(node.has_leaf_children?)
        node.children.each{|i| yield i} 
    else
        node.children.each{|i| bottom_up_traversal(i, &block)}
    end
end
###
bottom_up_traversal(@root){|this_node| puts this_node }
```

Comment: That's true, but I think he would be getting a `LocalJumpError` (or something like that) instead of an `ArgumentError` in that case. There has to be another bug somewhere.